# HttpResponseMessage.Content as an attachment for an email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, httpresponse, email-attachments

I have an API that returns an '.xls' file, using `HttpResponseMessage`. What I am trying to do is to get that file and attach it to an email that I am sending.

Please keep in mind that I can't change the API implementation, so, the response will always be `HtppResponseMessage`.

Comment: In this case you can not get this file like attachment. What you can do : its just write link to  page in your email , and in page call this API function

Comment: Having a link to the actual webpage, where the user should click on the available button for download (it has this functionality), it's not really working for me :(.

Comment: If you can't change API - you cant attach HttpResponseMessage to email.

Comment: Isn't there a possibility to temporary download that attachment in order to use it, and delete it afterwards?

Comment: You can't do it on the fly. You can download file - SAVE HE somewhere, then send mail (attach this file) and then delete it. Important part it SAVE File - I don't know what you can to do in your situation

Comment: Not problem. You are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, apparently there is a solution for my problem. What I had to do was to get the `HttpContent` from the API's `HttpResponseMessage` as `Stream`. After that, all the process was a piece of cake.

Here is the solution. It works great.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = _service.GetAPIResponse(...);
Stream data = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

var mailMessage = new MailMessage()
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(data, response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName));
```

I hope that this helps someone else as well.

Cheers.